# Multi rows and Multi columns input form with Lavarel Pivot table

Tags: javascript, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

In Laravel I have a pivot table with custom attribute and I need to create a form to make the users able to input values inside it from the GUI.

Pivot table is beetween **Students** and **Courses** and the custom attribute inside it is the **Student Certification Number**

Aside the usuals fields like *course_date* etc. I thought about creating a table like this to match the custom attribute with the single student.

[image: custom table]

The point is that I can't figure out how to create something similar.

- Multi rows (also possibility to add new rows)
- *student_name* is a select2 input, *certificate_num* is a simple string.
- On submit pass the value to to the controller with two array that looks like this:

  ```
  "students" => array:3 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "5"
  ] 
  "certificates_numbers" => array:3 [
   0 => "num1"
   1 => "num2"
   2 => "num4"
  ]
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with [this simple tutorial](https://blog.quickadminpanel.com/master-detail-form-in-laravel-jquery-create-order-with-products/).